# Change color actionBar Material design by source

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I would like to change the color of the ActionBar to style "materials design", but the method setbackgrounddrawable changes the style of the ActionBar to "holo". Does anyone know if there is a new method for "Android SDK L"? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "the method setbackgrounddrawable changes the style of the ActionBar to "holo"."? How are you calling this method?

Answer (score 1):

From code simply call `getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable()`

I have tested it and everything worked well. Try my code (bit longer but nice result), I'm using Appcompat but it works same across all APIs:

```
private void colorizeAB(){
        Random random = new Random();
        int color = Color.rgb(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                colorizeAB();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the colour at runtime then you have to take the object of your toolbar and then have to use **toolbar.setTitleTextColor()** method as shown below :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF557F"));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the action bar color in the Material theme, you can simply specify android:colorPrimary in your theme.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/my_branding_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: yes, this is for change the color primary in styles, but i like to change the color in source dynamically, thanks